# Finding raw text on disk drive

Tags: hard-drive, microsoft-word, data-recovery

I have lost a document I have worked very hard on. I have a backup that is three days old, but a lot of work has gone into it in the last three days.

Here is the details:

1. File still exists on my drive, but Word cannot open it.
2. Opening the file with a text editor shows plain text content not relevant to what I was working on - it contains content of a CSV file I worked on recently.
3. A error check on the disk indicates that there were "cross linking" problems with the disk and I fixed them.

Now - the fact that the file contains irrelevant content, makes me wonder if the text of my document can be recovered from the hard disk. I know I will most likely lose formatting and tables, and pictures and such, but I really need to get the text back.

The drive is a portable Seagate USB3 drive, and I have done checks in autorecover folders on my local machine where I was working, and did not find any copies there.

Any idea how I can scrub the disk for raw text? I know some phrases from the document by heart, so should be easy to find if it exist, and I have the tools. Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many softwares out there to help you out like:

1. Recuva
2. Easeus data recovery software
3. data rescue PC3

Comment: easeus data recovery helped me. Thank you so much!